# Get CSS height of HTML DOM element in non-pixel unit, in my case inches

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, height, pixel

EDIT: sorry about the inconsistencies with width and height in my question, it applies to both though.

EDIT 2: I still get an innaccurate value regardless of the zoom, doing this

`$('#selector').css('width',$('#selector').css('width'));` actually resizes the element.

I have a page element measured in inches. The firefox property inspector states the correct height `(8.5in)` but using `$('selctor').css('width')` it returns it in pixels `("815.66666px")`. This is problematic for me.

My use case is that I am toggling the size at one point in my script, and I want to be able to set it back to its default size later. In between toggling the size, and setting back to the default, the user may have zoomed the page. Due to firefox (and I think other browsers as well) less-than-perfect unit conversions, I get different round off errors based on the zoom level. For example, changing the zoom to various levels between `25%` and `300%` on my page yields the following results for the `css('width')` on the same element:

```
    >>>   $('#templateDiv0').css('width')
    "815.66666px"
    >>>  $('#templateDiv0').css('width')
    "815.76666px"
    >>>  $('#templateDiv0').css('width')
    "816.33334px"
    >>>  $('#templateDiv0').css('width')
    "816.13334px"
```

And so when I need to reset it back to the default size later, I have no guarantee that this is the correct size. I really would like it to just return (8.5in) to me. I guess the issue is that jQuery is retrieving it in its own way, and I would want to retrieve it in the way the property inspector does, which is by looking at the style sheet directly. Is there any way to do this?

The stylesheet for the page changes often, so hardcoding the value is not a good solution for me.

Comment: Browser zoom is there for convenience and is not intended to preserve layouts at 100% accuracy.

Comment: So how do I work around that?

Comment: Don't use inches at all. http://css-tricks.com/the-lengths-of-css/ Inches are for print design, not web.

Comment: Its a web tool designed to template a printable document, so using inches for all elements and sub elements makes sure the preview is exactly proportional...I guess I could just convert everything to pixels before hand to preserve the proportions...

Comment: If you want web pages to print perfectly, you're better off generating them as a PDF on the server. Print fidelity varies widely across browsers.

Comment: It actually has nothing to do with printing, the print copy is rendered independantly, this simply lets them template it and passes on their values to the renderer. Its just that the web tool must look as close to the print copy as possible

Comment: I figured out a way to do this without using the width and height. I was using it to move the elements out of view, I am using .show() and .hide() instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have 1366*768pixels on my 13inch screen
so 1inch = (1366*768pixels/13)px = 80699.07px;
1px = 13/(1366*768) inches = 1/80699.07 inches

unfortunately screen size is not given by api, so if you know the screen size then you can:

```
var size = 13;
var width =  $('#templateDiv0');
var widthInches = width * size/(window.screen.width * window.screen.height)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about storing the width of the element onReady, then when you click return to default, set the width back to the width you stored onReady.

Comment: thats exactly what I'm doing, the problem is that the width that jQuery reports is unusable. Setting it back to the width from onready results in a differently sized element than the original.

Comment: Is that before or after a zoom? Cause you could possibly disable the browser zoom functionality http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050841/disable-zooming-of-the-page-in-desktop-web-browsers-using-javascript-jquery

Comment: I need the user to be able to zoom. Also, I just found out it happens regardless of zooming.

Comment: You maybe running into margin/padding issues in your html/css.