# Force page zoom at 100% with JS

Tags: javascript, html, browser, zooming

I created a little game in Canvas, but I have a problem.  Some users who have the default zoom set to something other than 100% can't see the entire game page.

I have tried using this CSS:

```css
zoom: 100%;
```

This HTML

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0 , minimum-scale=1.0 , maximum-scale=1.0" />
```

And this JS:

```js
style="zoom: 75%"
```

Any ideas how to programatically set the page zoom?

Comment: You cannot reset the zoom

Comment: So i have to ask to set the zoom at 100%? ok thx .

Comment: HI How Can I ask to set zoom at 100%?

Comment: See this answer, maybe it help you: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050841/disable-zooming-of-the-page-in-desktop-web-browsers-using-javascript-jquery#14051622](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050841/disable-zooming-of-the-page-in-desktop-web-browsers-using-javascript-jquery#14051622)

Comment: See: [How to detect page zoom level in all modern browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1713771/1366033)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You can set `zoom` property on page load

```
document.body.style.zoom = 1.0
```

But, `zoom` is [not a standard property for all browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-zoom), I recommend using `transform` instead.

```
var scale = 'scale(1)';
document.body.style.webkitTransform =  scale;    // Chrome, Opera, Safari
 document.body.style.msTransform =   scale;       // IE 9
 document.body.style.transform = scale;     // General
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5RzJ8/

Comment: Hi Firat, I try ur code but it does not work for me. I run my application in IE 10. Can you please help me?

Comment: I think if I remember correctly that in ie, scale is in percent (0-100) instead of a multiplier (0-1) like the rest of the world.

Comment: This just transforms the div rather than affecting the browser's zoom level :(.

Comment: `for(i = 0; i < 100000; i++){
    setTimeout(() => 
 document.body.style.zoom = Math.random(), 1000)
}` try this in your console

Comment: Works and also does not. It does scale content but not the way browser does. With browser zooming it all looks nice, with all that scaling and zooming some page elements are totally broken.

Comment: `document.body.style.zoom = 1.0` can't work, because it's related to current zoom => `required zoom = current zoom * 1.0`. Correct solution has been post by Mehdi Souregi

Answer (score 11):

You can reset the code with this:

```js
$("input, textarea").focusout(function(){
    $('meta[name=viewport]').remove();
    $('head').append('<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">');

    $('meta[name=viewport]').remove();
    $('head').append('<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=yes">' );
});
```

Comment: I had no idea you could do this!
It didn't work for me to solve this problem I have with setting the zoom - but it is going to be super useful for other things!

Answer (score 7):

It is working in chrome 66 :

```
document.body.style.zoom = (window.innerWidth / window.outerWidth)
```

Answer (score 6):

I think, this is very helpful answer [how to detect page zoom level in all modern browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5078596/947687). Then [the answer](http://jsfiddle.net/dizel3d/1hzowb10/) to your question for IE:

```
document.body.style.zoom = screen.logicalXDPI / screen.deviceXDPI;
```

Answer (score 4):

The only way I found that works natively is in designing my HTML/CSS with the units "vw" and "vh" (% relative to the viewport) instead of "px". You can use it everywhere you used to put "px" (font-size, width, height, padding, margin, etc...). Very useful for a page designed to be display full screen only (no scroll) or "Kiosk-style". "vw" and "vh" are not affected by browser zoom.
See: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

Answer (score 2):

For mobile browsers, @Linden's answer worked the best for me on Chrome. However on mobile FF it needed some additional tweaks, I came to version that works in both browsers:

```
let restore = $('meta[name=viewport]')[0];
if (restore) {
    restore = restore.outerHTML;
}
$('meta[name=viewport]').remove();
$('head').append('<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">');
if (restore) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        $('meta[name=viewport]').remove();
        $('head').append(restore);
    }, 100); // On Firefox it needs a delay > 0 to work
}
```

Also, the restored page viewport tag must have explicit maximum-scale to allow zooming on Firefox after resetting, so I set it initially to this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=10">
```

Tested on mobile Chrome 76.0 and mobile Firefox 68.1.

Comment: A delay of 1 sec worked for me (Android webview)

Answer (score 1):

I'd try both solutions but the following is seems to be a bug in [echarts](https://echarts.apache.org/zh/index.html) which leads to [cursor deviated](https://github.com/apache/incubator-echarts/issues/12645).

```js
document.body.style.zoom = 1.25; // work but not to be expected.
```

I wonder if there any solution for the browser to directly modify the zoom ratio just like what `ctrl`+`+`/`-` effect.

Answer (score 0):

I have a css trick for this question, it's supported on chrome,firefox and ...
but it seems a bit complicated to implement.
You must give all dimensions including font size,margin, padding width, and height in [vw](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units).

you can test it by resizing your browser:

```css
div {
   padding:1vw;
   margin:1vw;
   font-size:4vw;
   width:50vw;
   height:10vw;
   background:red;
}
```

```html
<div>
text
</div>
```