# JavaScript - prevent page zooming

Tags: javascript, html, zooming

I have a web application that will be used on a tablet PC (on Internet Explorer). **EDIT : not a tablet, but a Windows 7 computer with a touch screen.**

The problem is that the user can pinch to zoom on the page (like ctrl-+).

Is there a way to disable it from JavaScript ? (like on mobile devices).

Or maybe change the User Agent to act like an iPad for example ? Will it work ?

Comment: Why not just use `<meta name="viewport" content="maximum-scale=1">`? See https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html

Comment: did you tried with media query's ?
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable zooming of the page in desktop web browsers using Javascript/Jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050841/disable-zooming-of-the-page-in-desktop-web-browsers-using-javascript-jquery)

Comment: @NarekMamikonyan: That is _not_ a Media Query, that is simply a viewport meta tag.

Comment: _“Or maybe change the User Agent to act like an iPad for example ? Will it work ?”_ – changing the User Agent will not make the browser itself act any differently …

Comment: @CBroe yes you right, I messed

Answer (score 6):

Use

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

in the `<head>` section of your document to prevent scaling the website on mobile devices. Important here is `user-scalable=no` which makes the trick.

**Edit**

Made some more research and you also got the option to add:

```
<meta name="MobileOptimized" content="640">
```

While `content="640"` is the `width` you want to set and behaves like `<meta name="viewport" content="width=640,user-scalable=no">`.

Read more about [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/iemobile/archive/2010/11/22/the-ie-mobile-viewport-on-windows-phone-7.aspx) and [here](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2011/03/14/managing-the-windows-phone-browser-viewport.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, but it is not a mobile device. Will it work with IE ?

Comment: A tablet pc is a mobile device ;) Mobile doesn't mean only smartphones but tablets as well. And yes it will work.

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9197067/test.html doesn't work. Am i I forgeting something ? In fact it is not a tablet, but a "touch screen computer" and it's running on Internet Explorer

Comment: You forgot `user-scalable=no`.

Comment: Thx again, but it still doesn't work. (I edited the link). Are you sure that it works with IE ? Do I have to change the user agent of the page ?

Comment: Unfortunately not, it seems to be for Windows Phone IE version only... I need it wih a standard IE on Windows 7. Thanks anyway

Comment: Second time I've seen this meta tag used. This does not work on a standard browser on a touch screen (tablet) pc.

Answer (score 4):

You can disable zoom in browser by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>-</kbd> or Using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> Key + Mouse wheel Up or down by this code.

```js
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
if (event.ctrlKey==true && (event.which == '61' || event.which == '107' || event.which == '173' || event.which == '109'  || event.which == '187'  || event.which == '189'  ) ) {
        event.preventDefault();
     }
    // 107 Num Key  +
    // 109 Num Key  -
    // 173 Min Key  hyphen/underscor Hey
    // 61 Plus key  +/= key
});

$(window).bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function (event) {
       if (event.ctrlKey == true) {
       event.preventDefault();
       }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
teste
```

Comment: How to do that without Jquery, but JS only?