# How can one block a persons ability to zoom by css or html

Tags: html, css

im trying to block the option to zoom (in or out) in my website.
i tried to put this meta code:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
```

but unfortunately no success...
any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You should add `maximum-scale=1.0`

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

But it is for mobile devices.

If you are using desktop, it is a bit complicated. You can use javascript to block some keys. Here are some useful links:

1. [Prevent zoom cross-browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27116221/prevent-zoom-cross-browser)
2. [Disable zooming of the page in desktop web browsers using Javascript/Jquery [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050841/disable-zooming-of-the-page-in-desktop-web-browsers-using-javascript-jquery)

Comment: @yoash Are you using desktop browser. My answer is related to only mobile devices.

Comment: yes i am, how can i block it to desktop browser, please help me im lost...

Comment: @yoash look at the links that I added.